# What path to enter in PyQt QIcon.setThemeSearchPaths() in pyqt on win7?

Tags: python, qt, windows-7, pyqt

As is written in the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qicon.html) I would like to edit `setThemeSearchPaths()` as from current code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    for path in QtGui.QIcon.themeSearchPaths():
        print "%s/%s" % (path, QtGui.QIcon.themeName())
```

it prints out:

```
C:/Python27/icons/
    :/icons/
```

And no icons are found. I would like to ask you what path do I have to pass as input argument in function `setThemeSearchPaths()` on win7?

As I found out the icons should be on path/file:

```
C:\Windows\system32\imageres.dll
```

But if I input a path to `.dll` file nothing happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows doesn't have any icon themes. Qt uses [freedesktop icon specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html).

Using default paths, either extract your icon theme to `C:/Python27/icons/` or embed it as a Qt resource.

You can try to download [Faenza Icons.](http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/Faenza-Icons-173323228) You should end up with file structure like:

```
icons/<theme name>/index.theme
icons/<theme name>/apps/
icons/<theme name>/actions/
...
```

Comment: I embeded `.qrc` compiled file to `.py` and it worked. I used this icon theme http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Win2-7+Pack?content=113264

but some icons are empty files, like `folder_open.png` - may I ask why? Has something went wrong when extracting files maybe?

Comment: For some reason the designer just didn't make that icon. You can always put your own.