# How to set a Python Qt4 window icon?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I tried to use one icon from:

1. https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html
2. [PyQt4 set windows taskbar icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432637/pyqt4-set-windows-taskbar-icon)

But it does not show up on the window:

[image]

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

# Create an PyQT4 application object.
a = QApplication(sys.argv)

# The QWidget widget is the base class of all user interface objects in PyQt4.
w = QWidget()

# Set window size.
w.resize(820, 240)

# Set window title
w.setWindowTitle("Hello World!")

# https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html
undoicon = QIcon.fromTheme("camera-web")
w.setWindowIcon(undoicon)

# Show window
w.show()

sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

I am on Windows 10 with:

1. Anaconda `conda --version` -> `conda 4.3.18`
2. Python `python --version` -> `Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda custom (32-bit)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qicon.html#fromTheme) says

> By default, only X11 will support themed icons. In order to use themed icons on Mac and Windows, you will have to bundle a compliant theme in one of your themeSearchPaths() and set the appropriate themeName().
>   This function was introduced in Qt 4.6.

Since you would need to gather a theme anyways to ship with the application, you could also just choose to collect some icons and specify the files directly.

```
w.setWindowIcon( QtGui.QIcon("folder.png") )
```

Comment: How to `bundle a compliant theme`?

Comment: I have no idea, but it's obvious that you haven't done that. ;-)

Comment: The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392213/what-path-to-enter-in-pyqt-qicon-setthemesearchpaths-in-pyqt-on-win7 seems to help.